# How can I manually trigger HBase balancer command using Rest API?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

From HBase shell the balancer can be triggered using `balancer` command.
Is there a way to do this using the provided `REST API`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot launch the `HBase` shell command `balancer` via `REST API`.